# A-frame: How to setup wall colliders

Tags: aframe

Can anyone tell me how to setup wall colliders? I have setup a room using OBJ files for the walls. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for Don McCurdy's "Walls" example:
https://sandbox.donmccurdy.com/vr/walls/

Note the addition of the physics component in the a-scene element. This is what gets the magic going.

You need to include the aframe-extras script along with aframe.

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a good solution nowadays, the best I found so far is to use a `nav-mesh`

The nav-mesh is a simple 3d object that represents the walkable area in your project.

Here is what you'll need:

1. To generate the nav-mesh, use the plugin https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-inspector-plugin-recast
2. To move the camera you will not use wasd-controls, but `aframe-extras`'s `movement-controls`

#### How to

Once the plugin is added to the page, follow these steps:

1. I found it was better to generate without the walls, so I hide the walls first, and make sure the floor ends where the walls would be. Also, keep all objects that user should not be able to pass through in their final place.
2. In the browser, use `ctrl + alt + i` to open the inspector
3. In the bottom part of the inspector, you can change cellSize and cellHeight to 0.1
4. Export and save it
5. in the HTML add a new asset:
   `<a-asset-item id="my-nav-mesh" src="assets/navmesh.gltf"></a-asset-item>`
6. Add a new entity that points to the nav mesh:
   `<a-entity gltf-model="#my-nav-mesh" nav-mesh position="0 -0.1 0" visible="false"></a-entity>`
7. Add the `movement-controls` to your camera Rig, with the `constrainToNavMesh: true;`. Here is how mine ended up:

```
<a-entity id="rig" movement-controls="constrainToNavMesh: true; speed: 0.8;" position="0 0 26">
   <a-entity id="camera"
      camera position="0 2.6 0"
      look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true">
   <a-cursor></a-cursor>
</a-entity>
```

#### Expected Result:

So, by adding the nav-mesh and using the movement-controls instead of WASD, for example, you will make your camera moveable only on the created mesh.

You can also make the mesh invisible (adding `visible="false` to the nav-mesh entity), and toggle its position on Z so it doesnt feel like a higher plane.

##### Source

I actually got this information structured from this amazing free youtube video, from Danilo Pasquariello.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y52czIft9OU

##### How my project is looking after doing the steps above (I just made the mesh visible again for this screenshot

[image: How my project is looking after doing the steps above (I just made the mesh visible again for this screenshot)]

Answer (score 0):

`kinematic-body.js` is deprecated.
Don McCurdy encourages the use of [teleportation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/faq.html#can-i-prevent-the-camera-from-going-through-obstacles)
See this post too: [Move camera in aframe with physics engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503796/move-camera-in-aframe-with-physics-engine)

Answer (score 0):

aframe inspector plugin didn't work on my project.
I did that temporary

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-aabb-collider-component@^2.2.1/dist/aframe-aabb-collider-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@3.0.3/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>

<script>
    let isStop = false
    AFRAME.registerComponent("cam", {
        init: function () {
            window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
                if (isStop) {
                    const camera = document.getElementById('camera')
                    if (e.key === 's' || e.key === 'a' || e.key === 'd') {
                        camera.setAttribute('wasd-controls-enabled', 'true')
                        isStop = false
                    }
                }
            })
            this.el.addEventListener("hitclosest", (e) => {
                console.log('ok');
                isStop = true
                this.el.setAttribute('wasd-controls-enabled', 'false')
            })
            this.el.addEventListener("hitstart", (e) => {
                isStop = true
                this.el.setAttribute('wasd-controls-enabled', 'false')
            })
        }
    })
</script>
<a-scene>
    <a-entity id="rig" position="0 .5 -1">
        <a-camera wasd-controls-enabled="true" cam id="camera" aabb-collider="objects: .collide"
            geometry="primitive: box" aabb-collider="objects: a-box">
            <a-cursor></a-cursor>
        </a-camera>
    </a-entity>
    <a-box color="blue" class="collide" width='1' height='1' position="0 1.6 -5">
    </a-box>
    <a-box color="red" class="collide" width='1' height='1' position="2 1.6 -5">
    </a-box>
    <a-box color="pink" class="collide" width='10' height='1' position="10 1.6 -5">
    </a-box>

</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's ammo, which is a library for aframes.
https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-physics-system/blob/master/AmmoDriver.md#ammo-shape
You could read Collision Filtering for the detailed solution.