# A-Frame, how to make it so that you can't go through planes and similar elements?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

When using the WASD keys, how to make it that you cannot go through planes as if they are walls?

Comment: You may need a `collision` component to detect collision, I detect this with planes bounding box. and you need disable `wasd-controls` when you hit the plane.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A-frame: How to setup wall colliders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625998/a-frame-how-to-setup-wall-colliders)