# Move camera in aframe with physics engine

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr, cannon.js

I am using a physics engine in my aframe application, and I want the camera to move when the user clicks a button.

I want to keep the physics engine properties so I am using applyImpulse as a method for motion.

Here is my example scene:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v2.3.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<a-scene physics>
<!-- Camera -->
<a-entity id="cameraWrapper" geometry="box" dynamic-body="mass:1" position="0 1 0" width="2" height="1" depth="2" listener>
<a-entity id="camera" camera universal-controls position="0 1 0" rotation="0 0 0">
</a-entity>
</a-entity>
<a-grid static-body position="0 0 0"></a-grid>
</a-scene>
<div>
<a id="impulseButton">Move</a>
</div>
```

The javascript method that is supposed to move the camera looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#impulseButton").on("click",function(){
    applyImpulse();
  });

function applyImpulse(){
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var z = 1;
    var el = $('#cameraWrapper')[0];
    el.body.applyImpulse(
       new CANNON.Vec3(x,y,z),
       new CANNON.Vec3().copy(el.body.position)
    );
  }
});
```

However, the movement seems not very smooth, and when the users uses WASD controls, the cameraWrapper entity remains at the old location. How can I move the camera with applyImpulse smoothly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`universal-controls`](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls) component is a replacement for `wasd-controls` and `look-controls` that is compatible out of the box with aframe-physics-system. The key case where this is helpful is in preventing the camera from going through obstacles, which [I don't recommend in VR](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/faq.html#can-i-prevent-the-camera-from-going-through-obstacles), but is still useful for desktop non-VR applications.

Usage:

```
<a-entity camera universal-controls kinematic-body></a-entity>
```

The `kinematic-body` component is added to detect collisions on the player. Here is a [more complete example](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/examples/walls/index.html).

---

> NOTE: Future versions of aframe-extras will probably not have support for `kinematic-body` and camera collisions, so you may be locked in at version 3.X.X. This is unfortunately necessary to support key VR cases better, like having physics for multiplayer experiences and running physics in a web worker for performance.

Comment: It does work, [live demo here](https://sandbox.donmccurdy.com/walls/). The source code for that demo is linked in the answer.

Comment: I understand that kinematic-body detects collisions, but I don't understand how this can be combined with applyImpulse or any other method that moves the camera to detect collisions when moving the camera programmatically. sorry if that wasnt clear in my question.

Comment: `kinematic-body` does not work with `applyImpulse()`, but when combined with `universal-controls` it automatically detects collisions and prevents the camera going through `static-body` or `dynamic-body` objects.

Comment: In other words, you can _either_ use `kinematic-body` with `universal-controls`, or you can use `dynamic-body` with `applyImpulse()`. The latter will likely require 100+ lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is just a movement question so js/aframe would be all you need. It should look like this. This is just a quick n dirty but should give you the idea. You can serach about player movement stuff and would find many ways to do this. Just change the key functions to button functions and you should be good to go.

So it would be more like this for all kind of entitys (cam, light, player.... ):

```
this.camMove = function(){
        // delta = change in time since last call (seconds)
            delta = clock.getDelta(); 
            var mDir = 100 * delta;
            moves = false;

            var mButtons = ["button1", "button2", "button3"];
            for (var i = 0; i < mButtons.length; i++)
            {
                if ( mButtons >= 0 )
                    moves = true;
            }

            if ( mButtons === button1 )
                cam.translateX( mDir );
            if ( mButtons === button2 )
                cam.translateX( -mDir );
            if ( mButtons === button3 )
                cam.translateY( -mDir );
                ................
                ............
                ........
}
```

clock should be a function in your aframe, but im not sure about it because i use three.js for things like this.

Comment: the problem with translateX and animations is that they are not recognized by the physics engine, only look controls do. Is there any way to use applyImpulse to do what you suggested?

Comment: To have this work with the physics engine (e.g. for collisions) you could replace `cam.translateX` with `cameraEl.body.applyImpulse(..., ...)`. See [docs for CANNON.Body.applyImpulse()](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_applyImpulse).

Comment: @DonMcCurdy this seems to only work then with dynamic-body examples. Could you provide an example that moves the kinematic-body camera entity for example with the vector 0,0,1, as in my question?

Comment: @bear Correct, you can't apply impulses to a kinematic body. You could attach a dynamic body to the camera instead, with `el.body.fixedRotation = true` to prevent rolling. But implementing this completely is probably hundreds of lines of code, so i cannot write it for you sorry.