# A-Frame static-body on a-entity

Tags: html, aframe

I am trying out on aframe physics

I can apply static-body properties on a shape object:

```
<a-sphere color="red" width="2" height="2" depth="2" position="2 1 -5" rotation="45 0 0" static-body></a-sphere>
```

But not on a a-entity object, i am still able to move through the object:

```
<a-entity static-body obj-model="obj:models/lamp_mesh.obj;mtl:images/lamp_mesh.mtl" rotation="0 90 0" position="5.46 0 0" animation></a-entity>
```

Is it only possible to apply the static/dynamic properties on a shape object?

Or i have done something wrong somewhere

I seen many tutorials of physics on shape object but none on a-entity object.

Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no issues with using `static-body` with any `<a-entity>` elements.
[Here](https://glitch.com/~aframe-model-physics) you have a link, where i use it with a `<a-entity>` with a gltf model.

---

There is a useful flag `debug: true` for the `physics` component:

```
<a-scene physics="debug: true">
```

If you don't see a wireframe around your object, then its possible there is no physics body attached to it.

---

Make sure your model is loaded properly, check the wireframe around it, if there is none, you can:

1) Convert your `.obj` model to the web standard `.gltf` (official converter [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter)) 
2) Create the `physics` bodies manually. From the [docs](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system):

```
<a-entity gltf-model="src: mug.glb"
      body="type: dynamic; mass: 5; shape: none;"
      shape__main="shape: cylinder;
                   height: 0.36;
                   radiusTop: 0.24;
                   radiusBottom: 0.24;"
      shape__handle="shape: box;
                     halfExtents: 0.15 0.18 0.04;
                     offset: 0.4 0 0;">
</a-entity>
```

Comment: the example in your link, camera still seems to be able to go through both gltf-model and the a-entity, i am guessing that the camera need to have something like a static-body properties?

Comment: The spheres should bounce off the head models https://aframe-model-physics.glitch.me/. I've added a listener for `model-loaded`, so they won't fall until the heads are present. I didn't attach any kind of body to the camera.

Comment: is it possible to make the camera unable to "go through" either the sphere or the head?

Comment: oh yes, i was missing out the kinematic-body properties. Thanks for the help again

Comment: It was simple with previous versions of `aframe-extras` and `aframe-physics`, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503796/move-camera-in-aframe-with-physics-engine) anwser, yet preventing the camera from moving through obstacles is not in the creators intention (since `aframe` is created for VR). If you attach a static body, to the camera, all dynamic bodies will bounce off, but you will still move through other static bodies. The easiest way to bounce off the camera accelerating it a bit in the opposite direction than the wall.